# Rosette formation: in which order are leafs created

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, botany, flowering

From the picture below, it seems that new leaves are formed something like this (if you imagine the plant as a regular, 12 hour clock):

new leaf at 12 o'clock, then at 7 o'clock, then at 2 o'clock, then at 9 o'clock, and so on.

I imagine it could be some things as simple as 'always add 190 degrees'. Are the exact rules for this documented somewhere for various plants?

[image: houseleek]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Spiral Phyllotaxis and the Golden Angle

The disposition of the leaves in your picture is not as simple as it seems. That's a [spiral phyllotaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllotaxis#Repeating_spiral), which can be very complicated.

The plant in your image is a houseleek, a plant from the Genus [*Sempervivum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempervivum).
In those plants, according to Jeremy Burgess (*Introduction to plant cell developmnent*):

> ... leaf primordia are separated from each other in an angular arc that approaches 137°.

By the way, 137° is (almost) the [golden angle (φ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_angle).

Here is an image explaining the phyllotaxis of *Sempervivum* (from Burgess, 1989):

[image]

Even more interesting is the pattern made by the 137.5° GA spiral of *Aloe polyphylla*:

[image]

Sometimes this can produce invisible spiral patterns, a phenomenon called *parastichy*:

[image]

Source: [Burgess, J. (1989). An introduction to plant cell development. 1st ed. Cambridge [etc.]: Cambridge University Press.](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=r808AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=sempervivum%20phyllotaxis&source=bl&ots=1v1EOD03No&sig=EgyBdujk25Bqspo9QzsDRlqidEs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjusZzo_9_TAhUIiLwKHfmrAzsQ6AEIVzAO#v=onepage&q=sempervivum%20phyllotaxis&f=false)

PS: I know that this is *off-topic*, but I'd like to share this video from Cristóbal Vila, which deals with Fibonnaci sequence, golden ratio and golden angle in nature. Look at the flower disposition at 1:44 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkGeOWYOFoA

Comment: excellent, thanks! also thanks for the video link!